# Proving an inequality on $\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n} \langle c_i ,c_j \rangle \times \langle l_i ,l_j \rangle$

Tags: inequality, inner-products

This is a question that stumped me during an exam I took today.

> Let $c_1,...,c_n,l_1,...,l_n$ be vectors of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\langle .,.\rangle$ denote the dot product.
>
> Prove that $$\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n} \langle c_i ,c_j \rangle \times  \langle l_i ,l_j \rangle \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n||c_i||^2 \right)\left( \sum_{i=1}^n||l_i||^2 \right)$$

Expanding a bit it is equivalent to proving that
$$\sum_{1\leq i \neq j \leq n} \langle c_i ,c_j \rangle \times  \langle l_i ,l_j \rangle \leq  \sum_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n} ||c_i||^2 ||l_i||^2 $$

But I don't know how to tackle this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a double application of Schwarz inequality, we obtain 
$$\langle c_i,c_j\rangle\cdot\langle l_i,l_j\rangle\leqslant 
\lVert c_i\rVert\cdot
\lVert c_j\rVert\cdot\lVert l_i\rVert\cdot
\lVert l_j\rVert,$$
hence, after a summation over $i$ and $j$, 
$$\sum_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\langle c_i,c_j\rangle\cdot\langle l_i,l_j\rangle\leqslant\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lVert c_i\rVert\cdot \lVert l_i\rVert\right)^2.$$
We conclude by an other application of Schwarz inequality to the vectors  $x:=(\lVert c_i\rVert)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ and $y:=(\lVert l_i\rVert)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how do you get the RHS of the second inequality ?

Comment: I use the first inequality, then I factor the element depending on $i$ in the sum over $j$.

Comment: Ok,  got it. Thanks.